# Downloading and opening a series of image urls

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7

What I am trying to do is download 2 images from URL's and open them after download. Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
set files='https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/cars/mclaren-f1-gtr-42852-400x250.jpg','http://www.dubmagazine.com/home/media/k2/galleries/9012/GTR_0006_EM-2014-12-21_04_GTR_007.jpg'
powershell "(%files%)|foreach{$fileName='%TEMP%'+(Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf);(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($_,$fileName);Invoke-Item $fileName;}"
```

Im getting 'Cannot find drive' A drive with the name 'https' cannot be found.

It's the `Split-path` command that is having problems but cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: `Split-Path` is meant for filepaths, not URIs.

Comment: I'd suggest `'%TEMP%\' + ($_ -split '\/')[-1]`

Comment: Worked a dream thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could get away with basic string manipulation but, if the option is available, I would opt for using anything else that is data aware. In your case you could use the `[uri]` type accelerator to help with these. I would also just opt for pure PowerShell instead of splitting between batch and PS.

```
$urls = 'https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/cars/mclaren-f1-gtr-42852-400x250.jpg',
    'http://www.dubmagazine.com/home/media/k2/galleries/9012/GTR_0006_EM-2014-12-21_04_GTR_007.jpg'

$urls | ForEach-Object{
    $uri = [uri]$_
    Invoke-WebRequest $_ -OutFile ([io.path]::combine($env:TEMP,$uri.Segments[-1]))
}
```

Segments will get you the last portion of the url which is a proper file name in your case. `Combine()` will build the target destination path for you. Feel free to add you invoke item logic of course.

This also lacks error handling if the url cannot be accessed or what not. So be aware of that possibility. The code above was meant to be brief to give direction.

Comment: Just a note, there's probably a reason for him using the `WebClient` class (Win7 has PSv2 by default which doesn't include `Invoke-WebRequest`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Entirely possible. However it would be trivial to adapt and downloading was not the issue in the first place. Without any input from the OP I don't see much point in adding more.